Parse every k-element subset of an n-element vector
My goal is to perform an operation on every k-element subset of n elements stored in a vec.
My current approach uses this bit-manipulation to generate integers with k set bits in lexicographic order. I.e., given one such integer, it modifies it to the next one in order.
pub fn set_next_bit_permutation(v: &mut u128) {
    let t: u128 = *v | (*v-1);
    *v = (t + 1) | (((!t & (!t).wrapping_neg()) - 1) >> (v.trailing_zeros() + 1))
}

Then, I use positions of the set bits as the indices, pulling out each index like this. Say I'm using perm: u128 to store my current permutation. This code would be inside a loop that runs until I check every permutation:
perm_copy = perm;
while perm_copy > 0 {
  cur_index = perm.trailing_zeros();
  // do something with cur_index
  perm_copy ^= 1 << cur_index;
}
set_next_bit_permutation(perm);

While this works and is pretty fast (important because we go through this many times), we're limited to size 128. Also, it feels like a hack.
Questions:

Does Rust have anything built-in to handle fixed-size subsets of Vecs? Or, I'm not married to Vecs if some other container handles this.
If not, is there a better, more idiomatic way to accomplish this?
Or, how could I modify this to handle more than length 128? Arbitrarily large?


@ChayimFriedman Speed is vital, but I need to handle more elements.

This is a good hack. It works, it's fast, and you can explain it clearly, even if it won't be obvious how it works from a first glance. Of course, it may be over-engineered if you don't really need the speed. But assuming you do, do you know n (or at least an upper bound) at compile time and it is just >128, or do you need a dynamic n?

@ChayimFriedman I don't know n at compile time. I could come up with an upper bound per size of input. That would require recompiling for each new input, but that's tolerable if it buys me bigger size without an egregious performance hit.

Then you essentially need a bigint. A natural extension of your current code. With proper bigint library, you can do that really fast, without allocating each turn.

Sorry, I always confuse those terms. The term for that is "combinations". itertools has that, too (and it will also be slow).

Hmm... This will be harder than it seems on a first look, since you create many temporaries. If you want to do that efficiently, you will need to find a way to avoid them. Alternatively, you can allocate few spare bigints, but this will less efficient.

It's actually easy and efficient to do this with a sorted array of k indices.
Lets sort in ascending order and produce arrays of indices in lexicographic order considering the highest index first.
So we initialize the array with the lowest indexes: A=[0, 1, ... k-1]
Then, to get the next array of subset indexes in order, just:

Find the smallest index i such that i == k-1 or A[i+i] > A[i]+1
Increment A[i]
Set the preceding elements to [0, 1, ... i-1]

When you increment A[k-1] to n, you're done.

Usually you only touch A[0].  it's amortized constant time if n is a bit bigger than k.  It's very likely a lot faster than whatever you're going to do with those indexes.  If you modify the vector subset in place, then you usually only need to modify the first element.

Both approaches are fast. I'm accepting this because it's also simple.

You just need a bigint. There are various bigint libraries in Rust, the fastest being rug. It links against GMP, though, which makes it LGPL-licensed and not work on Windows-MSVC.
Here's how your code can look with it (not tested):
use rug::{Assign, Integer};

pub struct Combinations {
    result: Integer,
    temp1: Integer,
    temp2: Integer,
    temp3: Integer,
}

impl Combinations {
    pub fn new(upper_bound_length: usize) -> Self {
        Self {
            result: Integer::with_capacity(upper_bound_length),
            temp1: Integer::with_capacity(upper_bound_length),
            temp2: Integer::with_capacity(upper_bound_length),
            temp3: Integer::with_capacity(upper_bound_length),
        }
    }
}

/// This is an operation `rug` doesn't natively provide. It can be accelerated more if it's a hotspot,
/// via SIMD and such.
fn trailing_zeros(v: &Integer) -> u32 {
    let mut result = 0;
    for &limb in v.as_limbs().iter().rev() {
        let trailing_zeros = limb.trailing_zeros();
        result += trailing_zeros;
        if trailing_zeros < gmp_mpfr_sys::gmp::limb_t::BITS {
            break;
        }
    }
    result
}

pub fn set_next_bit_permutation(v: &mut Combinations) {
    v.temp1.assign(&v.result - 1);
    v.temp1 |= &v.result;
    v.temp2.assign(!&v.temp1);
    v.temp1 += 1;
    v.temp3.assign(-&v.temp2);
    v.temp2 &= &v.temp3;
    v.temp2 -= 1;
    v.temp2 >>= trailing_zeros(&v.result) + 1;
    v.result.assign(&v.temp1 | &v.temp2);
}

Dependencies:
gmp-mpfr-sys = "1.6.4"
rug = { version = "1.25.0", default-features = false, features = ["integer"] }

Besides the optimized algorithms and implementation of rug, it has another killer feature: the ability to assign the result of a computation directly into another variable without an allocation (which it does with incomplete operations and assign()). The alternative for libraries like num-bigint, will be to first assign the left variable to the target then use op=.
If you are willing to recompile for every size, you can be even faster by using compile-time arbitrary sized integers, which will allow the compiler to fully unroll the loops. The bnum crate is an example of a crate that implements arbitrary-sized integers, although I don't know if it'll be as fast as rug because its implementation is not as optimized as GMP.

I'm not getting the right answer here. This may not be the issue, but what in set_next_bit_permutation() is equivalent to wrapping_neg()?

@Dave Sorry, I've made a typo there. Fixed it.
